# Code to disable RCP e4 application close button of the main window

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

IS there a way where i can disable RCP e4 application close button of the main window. i tried getting the active shell and adding event.doit = false . But that is not working. Application closes even though i click on yes or no.

Comment: It uses an IWindowCloseHandler object. Have to create an instance of it and updated the same to the context. By this we can atleast handle the close event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your handler:

```
public class WindowCloseHandler implements IWindowCloseHandler{
        @Override
        public boolean close(MWindow window) {
//          System.out.println("in window close handler");
            Object shell = window.getWidget();
            return MessageDialog.openConfirm((Shell) shell, "Confirmation",
                    "Do you want to exit?");
        }
}
```

Second put the handler in the window(s) context: I do it in the post construct method of any part in the application:
public class SamplePart {

```
...
```

@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent, 
        MApplication app,
        EModelService service
        ) {

```
        ... setup the part ...

WindowCloseHandler close_handler = new WindowCloseHandler();
java.util.List<MTrimmedWindow> wins = 
        service.findElements(app, null, null, null);
for(Object win : wins){
    if(win instanceof MTrimmedWindow)
    ((MTrimmedWindow)win).getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, close_handler);
    else if(win instanceof MWindow)              ((MWindow)win).getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, close_handler);
}
```

}